# deploying smartcontract to ganache-desktop instead of ganache-cli with brownie

Tags: solidity, ganache, ganache-cli, brownie

i have a smartcontract developed with brownie. I want to deploy it to ganache. If i run my deployment script  `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`, brownie deploys the smartcontract with `ganache-cli`. But i want to deploy it to the desktop version of ganache so i can use it in a more convenient manner. I can have a look at my networks with `brownie networks list` and i can see different networks like Ethereum mainnet, Ropsten etc. and the Development networks:

```
Development
  ├─Ganache-CLI: development
  ├─Geth Dev: geth-dev
  ├─Hardhat: hardhat
  ├─Hardhat (Mainnet Fork): hardhat-fork
  ├─Ganache-CLI (Mainnet Fork): mainnet-fork
  ├─Ganache-CLI (BSC-Mainnet Fork): bsc-main-fork
  ├─Ganache-CLI (FTM-Mainnet Fork): ftm-main-fork
  ├─Ganache-CLI (Polygon-Mainnet Fork): polygon-main-fork
  └─Ganache-CLI (XDai-Mainnet Fork): xdai-main-fork
```

since using the `brownie run scripts/deploy.py` without the `--network` option deploys it to the development network, i guess something has to be configured so it is not using the `Ganache-CLI`. I cannot find a way to deploy it to my ganache desktop. I have seen in a tutorial, that brownie usally automatically connects to ganache desktop via RPC-Client, if its running. But on my computer it is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

okay. I found the solution. I can add a local network in my network list with :

```
brownie networks add Ethereum ganache-local host=http://127.0.0.1:7545 chainid=5777
```

where `ganache-local` is a name i choose and where `host + chainid` is from the running Ganache-desktop version.
After running that command you can see a Success message:

```
SUCCESS: A new network 'ganache-local' has been added
  └─ganache-local
    ├─id: ganache-local
    ├─chainid: 5777
    └─host: HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545
```

if you run now `brownie networks list`, under the `Ethereum` section you will see the new `ganache-local`

```
Ethereum
  ├─Mainnet (Infura): mainnet
  ├─Ropsten (Infura): ropsten
  ├─Rinkeby (Infura): rinkeby
  ├─Goerli (Infura): goerli
  ├─Kovan (Infura): kovan
  └─ganache-local: ganache-local
```

now i can run  `brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network ganache-local` and deploy to ganache-desktop

you can delete the network with `brownie networks delete ganache-local`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your Brownie is looking for a server in the localhost port 8545 (a legacy config). The Ganache Desktop app, by default runs it in the 7545. If you change the port to 8545 it should be able to pick it up automatically and not run an instance of ganache-cli instead.